# What happens when someone manually updates app during staged rollout of app updates on Google play store?

Tags: android

Had a question regarding "staged rollout" of apps on the google play store. If my app is currently going through a staged rollout, and someone outside of the staged rollout group tries to manually update the app, do they get the new version or the old version? More info on staged rollouts - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149#increase

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "tried to manually update the app."

If the user gets the APK through something like APKMirror, then they just get the app early. Google won't present the update to them because they already have the latest version.

If the user checks for updates instead, like most people do, it just won't show up. That's how staged rollouts work. As far as the user is concerned, if the update hasn't yet reached them, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, got it. So the user wont see the update option if he goes to the app store from his device?

Comment: Right. That's why stated rollouts exist.

Comment: This is not that helpful a comment @TheWanderer, this is a confusing subject and I believe the behaviour is different between iOS and Android staged rollouts.